# Какая команда изменяет размер окна vim?

Tags: vim, vimrc

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ctrl + shift + h/j/k/l изменялись размеры окна на 1 символ/линию. Я знаю, что для перехода между окнами есть команда wincmd:

```
nmap <silent> <C-k> :wincmd k <CR>
nmap <silent> <C-l> :wincmd l <CR>
nmap <silent> <C-h> :wincmd h <CR>
nmap <silent> <C-j> :wincmd j <CR>
```

Но какая команда отвечает за размеры окна? Знаю только про ctrl + w + +/-/</>

Comment: `Ctrl-w >`, `Ctrl-w <`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy А как прописать эти команды в .vimrc?

Comment: Зачем вы хотите их туда прописать? Они работают из коробки, менять .vimrc не надо.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я хочу назначить на клавиши ctrl + shift + h/j/k/l изменение окна, чтобы его было удобнее изменять, по 1 пункту

Comment: Читайте документацию по `*map`.

Comment: А ещё `:help ^W`, там всё есть. И удачи с мапингом клавиш с `shift`.

Comment: В Cygwin и Vim 7.4 увеличить/уменьшить высоту окна: `nmap <8b> <C-W>+` / `nmap <8a> <C-W>-`. Причём `<8b>` и `<8a>` нужно вводить буквально, т.е. сначала `ctrl+v`, потом `ctrl+shift+k`. В других условиях ввод `ctrl+shift+буква` скорее всего будет другим.

Comment: @hobo-mts , у меня не работает привязка к ctrl-W через map :(

Comment: Я делал так: `:nmap <8b> <C-W>+`. Это нужно ввести в командной строке или добавить в `.vimrc`. `<8b>` при помощи `ctrl+v`, затем `ctrl+shift+k`. А `<C-W>+` нужно набрать буквами

Comment: @hobo-mts , скорее всего я неправильно понимаю... После ввода `:nmap <8b> <C-W>+` я пробую ввести `8b`, но курсор перемещается на 8 слов назад... Что вы имеете ввиду под `crtl + v`? Это ведь визуальный режим

Comment: `ctrl+v`  в режиме ввода Vim или в командной строке Vim

Comment: @hobo-mts спасибо

Comment: `ctrl+v`  в режиме ввода Vim или в командной строке Vim ожидает ввода следующего символа литерально. Т.е. `:nmap <8b> <C-W>+` это `:nmap ` вводится буквами, потом `ctrl+v`, Vim ждёт следующего нажатия `ctrl+shift+k`, которое отображается как `<8b>`. А дальше опять буквы. Это в терминале Cygwin (mintty в качестве xterm). Как там на другой стороне, не знаю. Долго думал и набирал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось сделать так, чтобы стрелки на клавиатуре изменяли пропорции окон. Конечно, этими клавишами в vim пользоваться не принято, однако, я думаю, что было бы удобно их переопределить следующим образом:

```
map <Left> <C-W><
map <Right> <C-W>>
map <Up> <C-W>-
map <Down> <C-W>+
```

К сожалению, на  у меня не реагируют клавиши

Но есть и еще одно решение: [этот плагин](https://github.com/simeji/winresizer)